# css - 2 child containers not sitting alongside each other

Tags: css

I have a parent container, that has child containers within it. 2 child containers take up 60% width and 40% width respectively. They have no margin, and they have padding, but use box-sizing so this is included in the width. But for some reason they don't sit side by side. If I change one of them to 39% width then it looks fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Example can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/Rcaet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **display:inline-block** which by default have some space. For this you have to use a **font-size:0** hack. Write like this:

```
.parent-container {
    font-size:0;
}
.parent-container > div{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rcaet/8/

Comment: Super thanks, now I understand. Although I do not know why they made it work this way, seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything "wrong".  Your `borders` also take up `width`.  So having borders means you will need to make the boxes smaller, hence the `39%`.

Comment: The borders were only added so I could see where the boxes were, the same problem is there if I have no borders...and yes, I uses box-sizing to include the borders in the width regardless

Answer (score 0):

You have to add floatings. Add a `float: left` to both container 2 and 3. But could still give a problem due the width of the borders in some browsers. So, indeed, reduce one of the boxes witdh.

Comment: But surely there must be a reason what I have done is not working as intended? I wanted to stay clear of floating elements as I then need to think about surrounding elements and clearings etc plus the borders haven't made any difference as I have used box-sizing